# Filtering posts by category name based on page's slug

Tags: functions, loop, page-template

I've created a page template and the goal is to create a loop that gets all posts by category name. The category name is passed from the slug of the page name. I haven't been able to get this to work entirely.

**EDIT** Here's my function for this loop (updated from answers):

```
global $post;
$page_slug = $post->post_name;

$category_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'category_name' => $page_slug
));

if ($category_query->have_posts()) :
    while ($category_query->have_posts()) :
        $category_query->the_post();
        $output = '<h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h2>';
        $output .= '<div class="entry-content" itemprop="text">'.get_the_content().'</div>';
    endwhile;
else :
    $output = '<h3>No posts found under "'.$page_slug.'"</h3>';
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();

echo $output;
```

I screwed up somewhere, as all I get is a blank white page. Any suggestions on how to fix my loop to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Comment: FWIW, this template built on the Genesis framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You are missing an `endwhile;`.
2. Since you are trying to concatenate, you need to use `get_*` for title, permalink and content.
3. You are using `$page_slug` here and `$post_slug` there. Just use one and the same variable. ;)
4. Put the condition of the `while` loop inside brackets.

See updated code:

```
global $post;
$page_slug = $post->post_name;
$args = array(
    'category_name' => $page_slug
);
$category_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($category_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($category_query->have_posts()) {
        $category_query->the_post();
        ?>
        <h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <div class="entry-content" itemprop="text"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
        <?php
    }
} else {
    ?>
    <h3>No posts found under "<?php echo $page_slug; ?>"</h3>
    <?php
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see few problems in your code.

1. Main cause is, your While loop is not closing, close it before the `else:`. This is the reason you are getting blank screen. You should turn on php errors to avoid blank screen for any future fatal errors.
2. use `get_the_title()` instead of `the_title()` and `get_the_content()` instead of `the_content()`